# Python script works locally but not on AWS Lambda Container

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I'm trying to run a linear optimization problem using `scipy` within AWS Lambda. `scipy` is over the limit to be added as a layer, so I've created a container and deployed to AWS Lambda. I was able to run a script that imports and uses basic parts of `scipy`, so I know the process works in general but it's getting hung up on certain functions. Here is my entire script:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
from scipy.optimize import milp, LinearConstraint, Bounds

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Constraints
    maxSal = 3000
    totalItems = 4

    # Setup variables
    itemId = pd.DataFrame([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], columns=['itemId'])
    itemCount = pd.DataFrame([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], columns=['itemCount'])
    itemCost = pd.DataFrame([710, 720, 730, 740, 750, 760, 770, 780, 790, 800], columns=['itemCost'])
    itemValue = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110]

    # Dummy DF to be used to select the optimal items
    itemDF = pd.concat([itemId, itemCount, itemCost], axis=1)

    # Compile all constraint vectors
    ConVec_StaticAllFixed = pd.concat([itemCount, itemCost], axis=1)
    print(ConVec_StaticAllFixed)
    print(type(ConVec_StaticAllFixed))

    # Setup constraints
    ConVal_AllGT = [totalItems, 0]
    ConVal_AllLT = [totalItems, maxSal]

    # Setup problem 
    A = scipy.sparse.csc_array(
        scipy.sparse.vstack((
            scipy.sparse.csr_array(ConVec_StaticAllFixed.iloc[:,i]) for i in range(len(ConVec_StaticAllFixed.columns))
        )))

    # All decisions are binary
    integrality = np.ones(shape=len(itemValue), dtype=np.uint8) 
    bounds = Bounds(
        lb=np.zeros_like(itemValue),
        ub=np.ones_like(itemValue),  # 685
    )

    ## Scrub things up so it'll run ##
    ConValGT_MILP = np.block(ConVal_AllGT)
    ConValLT_MILP = np.block(ConVal_AllLT)
    milpValues_Final = pd.Series(itemValue).astype(float)

    # Run milp
    result = milp(
        c=-milpValues_Final, integrality=integrality, bounds=bounds,
        constraints=(LinearConstraint(A=A, lb=ConValGT_MILP, ub=ConValLT_MILP),),
        options={'time_limit':2},
    )

    if result.success:
        outputs = pd.Series(name='Assigned', data=result.x)
        selections = outputs[outputs > 0.5].index
        filtered_selections = [x for x in selections if x < len(itemDF.index)] # only keep selections within itemDF
        itemDFSolved = itemDF.loc[filtered_selections]
        itemDFSolved["ItemValue"] = milpValues_Final
    else:
        itemDFSolved = pd.DataFrame()
        
    print(itemDFSolved)
    totalVal = sum(itemDFSolved.ItemValue)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'response': json.dumps('Successfully ran scipy MILP in lambda!'),
        'body': totalVal
    }
```

I've confirmed that this works locally, it spits out an optimized total value of 240 which is correct. However on AWS Lambda it's getting hung up on `scipy.sparse.vstack` which is used to build the matrix that gets optimized. Here is the error traceback in aws:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "iteration over a 0-d array",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "702c28fc-a594-4b7b-a984-d911df3e0fad",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/my_lambda_function.py\", line 29, in lambda_handler\n    scipy.sparse.vstack((\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_construct.py\", line 781, in vstack\n    return _block([[b] for b in blocks], format, dtype, return_spmatrix=True)\n"
  ]
}
```

So to me it seems like the error stems from the lambda function reading `ConVec_StaticAllFixed` as a scalar rather than a pandas dataframe since the error refers to it as a 0-d array. But in the cloud watch logs I can see that it prints out the type as `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`:

[image: Cloudwatch Logs]

So I'm stumped. I'm pretty new to containers and aws in general so if you have advice on how to sort through differences between local and containerized code.

Comment: This is because you're running a different version of scipy locally compared to in Lambda.  [A change](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/c603df0b91003e756bd751553baa7a15dd61ac39#diff-139795d27596cd4bc81110c1a0319c87147cafe9338b8e008cccf8a06b4dab4eR624) to the library passes the blocks param to `np.asarray()`, which does not support generators.  So, if you change `scipy.sparse.vstack((` to `scipy.sparse.vstack(list(` to expand the generator, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply this worked! So this is probably more of a containers question than it is an AWS question, but how would I even know that's the case? And why wouldn't the same local scipy library be uploaded to my lambda container? Again very new to this so I'm sorry if these aren't the right questions to ask

Comment: As a guess, if you followed some directions like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html) to create a container image, you created a requirements.txt file with the line "`scipy`" in it.  This would have installed the latest version of scipy during image creation rather than whatever's on your machine.  If you used the scipy version shown from a `"pip freeze`" like "`scipy==1.11.4`" then you would use the same version on your machine and in the container.